# Xrdp connection Issue: Windows to Ubuntu 2004 focal

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

I need to connect to a machine installed via a kickstarter.cfg file. The ks file looks like this:

```
# If you select ftp, the mirror/country string does not need to be set.
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string http://archive.ubuntu.com
d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
d-i mirror/codename string focal
#d-i mirror/suite string focal
...
### Package selection
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard, ubuntu-desktop, print-server, openssh-server, server
d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server update-motd
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select none
```

So the ubuntu-desktop gnome is bein installed there

Then I start a late command where I install xrdp with this command line

```
..
sudo apt update
apt install tightvncserver xrdp xserver-xorg-core xorgxrdp
apt upgrade -y
adduser xrdp ssl-cert
#I know this is not secure but its only in a local home network
systemctl restart xrdp
ufw allow 3389
...
```

Then when the system is installed I connect with a windows machine but I get this error.

[image: picture xrdp]

I checked some forums and tried out the solutions proposed like changing the **/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini** by setting the following code

```
[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=0.0.0.0
port=-1
```

but didn't work and I did not find any other information to solve this. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.
Xrdp works perfectly fine with the focal distribution.

The problem was due to the `sources.list` file copied in the `/etc/apt/` directory during the network installation, which is a roadmap for the system to know where it may download files for installation and upgrades (I didn't know that):

I needed to upgrade the "bionic" part to "focal" to get this:

```
deb http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
deb http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
deb http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
```

And after this, when I ran

```
..
sudo apt update
apt install tightvncserver xrdp xserver-xorg-core xorgxrdp
apt upgrade -y
adduser xrdp ssl-cert
#I know this is not secure but its only in a local home network
systemctl restart xrdp
ufw allow 3389
...
```

It worked perfectly fine to connect via RDP.